# How do I include a count of the total number of records not processed in a query?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in T-SQL:

```
Select distinct ExperimentID as expid, count(xa) as num_events, 
    (select count(*) from Simulations group by ExperimentID) as total_readings 
from Simulations where xa>180 and ExperimentID in
(select ExperimentID from parameters where sensorerror = 1 and controlrange = 2 and exogdexcurve <> 4) 
group by ExperimentID 
Order by num_events desc
```

The query rightly fails with message 512, as it returns multiple records when it's expected to return just one (to line up with the other single record parts of the query). I'm basically look to compare the total number of xa (sensor reading) to the number of xa that experience an event; xa>180. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you show sample data and desired results? Why are you using DISTINCT *and* GROUP BY? Is it possible the subquery should be correlated (e.g. alias the outer Simulations table as s and then inside the subquery `WHERE ExperimentID = s.ExperimentID`)?

Comment: Distinct because ExperimentID is part of a compound key, therefore it appears multiple times in the table. The group by is there to get a count of the number of events for each ExperimentID, and not just overall.

Comment: But you're grouping by ExperimentID, which already limits the output to one row per ExperimentID. Again, sample data and desired results would be helpful in understanding what your query is really supposed to do, because it's not obvious from just reading it, and it's possible there is a more efficient way to get your desired results than what you are currently using (depending on your version of SQL Server - please always tag with your specific version or include the output of `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion');` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the immediate problem, change this:

```
Select distinct ExperimentID as expid, count(xa) as num_events, 
    (select count(*) from Simulations group by ExperimentID) as total_readings 
from Simulations where xa>180 and ExperimentID in (...
```

To this:

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT isn't needed on top of GROUP BY
  ExperimentID AS expid, 
  COUNT(xa) AS num_events, 
  (
    SELECT count(*) 
      FROM dbo.Simulations -- schema prefix always, please
      WHERE ExperimentID = s.ExperimentID -- need to correlate per expid
      GROUP BY ExperimentID
  ) AS total_readings 
FROM dbo.Simulations 
WHERE xa > 180 AND ExperimentID IN (...
```

You can probably do this more efficiently* like this, though this is completely untested and I don't know if it matches your current results:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT 
    expid = ExperimentID,
    xa, 
    num_events = COUNT(CASE WHEN xa > 180 THEN xa END) OVER (PARTITION BY ExperimentID),
    total_readings = COUNT(xa) OVER(PARTITION BY ExperimentID)
  FROM dbo.Simulations AS s
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
     SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Parameters
       WHERE sensorerror = 1 AND controlrange = 2 AND exogdexcurve <> 4
       AND ExperimentID = s.ExperimentID
  )
  GROUP BY ExperimentID, xa
)
SELECT expid, num_events, total_readings
FROM x
WHERE xa > 180;
```

<sup>* Depending on indexes etc.</sup>

Comment: There's a clustered index on ExperimentID, CycleCount in dbo.Simulations. How do you design a query to be efficient? My queries usually only run for 1-5min, which I figured was to be expected with 76M rows.

Comment: `How do you design a query to be efficient?` There are entire books and week-long training courses dedicated to just that question.